# Error something to do with "libpcl_ros_tf.so" after migrating to Fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just migrated from Electric to Fuerte. But after running a node via rosrun command, I received an error message as below:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpcl_ros_tf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Running the command "env | fgrep ROS" as suggested by @joq I receive:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/abc/code/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=fuerte
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47968/error-something-to-do-with-%22libpcl_ros_tf.so%22-after-migrating-to-fuerte/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
$ dpkg -S libpcl_ros_tf.so
ros-fuerte-perception-pcl: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_tf.so
```

Do you have `ros-fuerte-perception-pcl` installed?

EDIT: I would try to get the basic Fuerte Ubuntu Debian package install working first, before tackling any source overlays. What does this print?

```
env | fgrep ROS
```

EDIT2: That mostly looks right. My system defines a few other things that could be significant:

```
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/joq/ros/fuerte_dev
ROS_DISTRO=fuerte
```

Also, my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ends with this:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

I don't know if any of that matters, but it's worth a try.

EDIT3: What if you reduce the package path to the minimum?

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

EDIT4: Do you have this defined?

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:
```

EDIT5: Frustrating, and I'll be away for the next few hours.

Does your node have `<depend package="pcl_ros">` in its manifest.xml?

EDIT6: For future readers: when upgrading to a new ROS distribution, *always* rebuild your source trees from scratch. Either use `make clean` or check out a new working copy. The results of not doing that can be quite strange.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
I have the library and in the path like above and when I install that package, it said it's already installed. Is this a bug in the Fuerte path management because it couldn't be able to search it automatically?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-11**:
More likely there is something wrong with your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. There are some differences in the way the Fuerte environment variables are set up. Try sourcing /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash directly.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
It's already set as source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash in my bashrc BTW and only that  which is "source"d. Any other alternatives to resolve this?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
Or do I need to apply the overlay(http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays)? No need right because I just follow step-by-step instruction from this(http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu).

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
@joq: I'm not on Debian anyway, I'm on ubuntu, perhaps I didn't get you.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
I've tried to append and add some more configuration  as you suggested, but still not resolved.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
@joq: Reducing the package path also doesn't improve.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
@joq: Yes, I do have. The same I receive as "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:".

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-11**:
@joq: Yes, it has the dependency.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-12**:
I can't think what else to try right now. Maybe someone else has some better suggestions. How did you set up your workspace?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-12**:
I just use workspace from my previous Electric and define it as "export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/abc/code/ros_workspace" in .bashrc. Is it not the correct way of doing it?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-12**:
Did you `make clean` and rebuild everything with Fuerte?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-12**:
@joq: My bad..I really forgot it to clean it up. It's now working out of the box! Thanks a lot..

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-13**:
Ahh. Sorry I did not think of that earlier. Glad it's working now.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-13**:
So do I, but your debugging/tweaking is superb! Thanks again..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-13**:
IMHO, pertaining to your "EDIT6", it is worthwhile to include it somewhere in any tutorial targeting at beginners like me..because not everybody(beginners) will possibly read this thread.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-13**:
I agree that it could be clearer, but am not sure where to say it. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-13**:
Just leave it here is also ok. Still beneficial..